# How to extract area information from a raster based on a DEM or contour lines

Tags: qgis, dem, contour

I have a raster representing the distribution of a specific land cover type - the raster values are 1 for where the land cover type is present and 0 where it isn't.

I also have a DEM with 5m resolution from which I extracted contour lines, and I want to know how much of that land cover type (in terms of area) falls inside each 200m elevation band (0-200, 200-400, etc.).

Can anyone suggest the best way to do this in QGis? I thought about Zonal statistics but I need polygons for that and not lines. Or is it better to use the DEM directly? I'm not sure if that would be a good option because the rasters have different resolutions (2 m vs 5 m) and their grids aren't aligned.

Comment: The fastest approach is to reclass your DEM raster to integer and go zonal stats between rasters. Don't worry much about different cell sizes, decent GIS will take care of it. If zonal stat between rasters doesn't exist in QGIS, convert output of reclass into polygons first